# REGEX in python2.7

Tags: python, python-2.7

I cannot seem to figure out how to write a regex to match on if all match in python:

- {'ERROR_CODE': 500}
- {'ERROR_CODE': 404}
- {'ERROR_CODE': 501}
- {'ERROR_CODE': 409}

I need the regex to match `{'ERROR_CODE':` first, which can be followed be either 5XX OR 4XX, and ending with }

i am able to specify and get it to work, how to make it match on the entire range 400-499 or 500-599.

```
// python snippet
err_pattern = re.compile("{\'ERROR_CODE\': 500}|{\'ERROR_CODE\': 404}")
if all(err_pattern.match(str(values)) for values in self.set.values()):
    output.append('All are 4XX and 5XX')
```

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

> how to make it match on the entire range 400-499 or 500-599.

The 4 and 5 are constant, and the second and third number are all 0-9 digits. Therefore you can make a regex like this:

```
re.compile(r"\{'ERROR_CODE': [45]\d{2}\}")
```

Which matches number starts with 4 or 5, followed by 2 digits.

Answer (score 1):

This is one way you could do it:

```
import re
values = ["{'ERROR_CODE': 500}",
          "{'ERROR_CODE': 404}",
          "{'ERROR_CODE': 501}",
          "{'ERROR_CODE': 409}]"]

err_pattern = re.compile("\{\'ERROR_CODE\': [45]\d{2}\}")

for value in values:
    if err_pattern.match(value):
        output = "All are 4XX and 5XX"
    else:
        output = "Some values are not error codes"
        break

print output
# All are 4XX and 5XX
```